# PHPSpreadsheet is suddenly very slow - building spreadsheet with less than 5000 rows

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Suddenly, PHPSpreadsheet is extremely slow. I'm building a spreadsheet 30 columns wide with less than 5000 rows. I upgraded from 1.10.1 to 1.11.0 on 3/23/2020. So if this has been an issue since then, I am only just noticing now.

I can confirm the execution of the query and iterating through the results (while storing them in a 2 dimensional array) takes less than a second.

It seems nearly all of the time is spent on these three lines:

```
$activeSheet->fromArray($finalArray, NULL, 'A2');  //Well over a minute
```

and

```
$activeSheet->setTitle('My Export');  //Between 5 and 10 seconds.
```

and

```
$objWriter->save('php://output'); // About a minute
```

My code pertaining to PHPSpreadsheet:

```
$spreadsheet = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$activeSheet->SetCellValue('A1', $columnNames['Column 1']);
$activeSheet->SetCellValue('B1', $columnNames['Column 2']);
...
$activeSheet->SetCellValue('AD1', $columnNames['Column 30']);
$activeSheet->fromArray($finalArray, NULL, 'A2'); // $finalArray is a 2 dimensional array with my data (position based, not using named keys) 
$activeSheet->setTitle('My Worksheet');

$activeSheet->getStyle("A1:AD1")->getFont()->setBold(true);

$objWriter = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="My Export.xlsx"');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

An xdebug profile trace reveals 90% of time being spent in `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->fromArray`. I also see `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->getCell` using 145 MB of memory and `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->createNewCell` using 101 MB of memory. Those two calls are called somewhere within the `->fromArray` call.

I believe I'm using the suggested methods to improve performance as mentioned on other questions. But in most questions, they are having performance issues on spreadsheets with many more rows than I. Additionally, something seems off as my xDebug profile trace is 500MB large (yes, MB, half a gig).

Is there anything else I can do to improve the performance? Am I doing anything incorrectly? Is this behavior highly unusual given the amount of data?

Comment: Any thoughts?? Same problem here.

Comment: No, I never figured this out.  I ended up using native RPG to provide an export. However, a trace showed there were ALOT of time spent in calls to PHP's `iconv` function. For a bit I thought if I specified data types of my cells and such I could eliminate those calls, but I was unsuccessful. @chuckedw